# Insert a new line in shiny's modalDialog

Tags: r, popup, shiny

In my shiny app I would like to have a popup window with some text. To make the text more readable I would like to include some linebreaks, but so far I have failed. Any idea how would I do that? I am currently using modalDialog()

```
 ui = basicPage(
actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
),
server = function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$show, {
  showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "My text",
    "This is the first line. 
     This should be the second."
  ))
})
}
```

I have tried: br(), \n and several variations of those. Nothing worked.

Help!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can wrap it in `HTML()` and then use `<br>`, similar to your attempt mentioned above. So you could use instead: `HTML("This is the first line.<br> 
      This should be the second.")`

For the full app, see below:

```
ui = basicPage(
  actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
)
server = function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "My text",
      HTML("This is the first line.<br> 
      This should be the second.")
    ))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```